# creating text file throws error

Tags: php

I am a php beginner.I want every time when the web page is open to create a file that does not exist. But every time when I run the program I have an error teling me that the file was not created.
This is my code:

```
$ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if(!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime'])){
  setcookie('firsttime', 'no');
  $myfile = 'file/form'.$ip.'.txt';
  if(file_exists($myfile) == FALSE){
    $fo = fopen($myfile, 'w');
    $code = '<form action = "" method = "post">';
    fwrite($fo, $code);
    fclose($fo);
  }else{
    unlink($myfile);
    $file = new File();
  }

}
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: do you have write access to the directory you are creating the file?

Comment: are you doing this locally on windows? Are you sure you're not getting a local IPv6 address? Those contain `:` characters, which are illegal in Windows filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ourFileName = "testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

Do this to open a file, and it will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure but that would result in a pretty weird file name.

```
$myfile = 'file/form'.$ip.'.txt';
```

If my ip is 1.0.0.01.23 (really random and pretty weird) the file name would be:

```
file/form.1.0.0.01.23..txt
```

Try saving a file with that name in notepad.

Comment: it should be `file/form1.0.0.01.23.txt` as the leading and trailing `.` are the concatenation operator in php. As far as the ip goes, an ip address only consists of four number blocks not five. Your ip is invalid...